# How to change only one object in a large state array of objects using Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, use-state

I have the following state:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([{id:1, marks: 1} , {id:2, marks: 20}, {id:3, marks: 30}, {id:4, marks: 40}])
```

And I want to write a function which takes in an `id` and increases the `marks` of that particular `id` by 1 using `setData` (or any other method)

Comment: How would you do it? Did you give it a try? Could you share your attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly for better readibility - exclude that array:
push that transformation logic inside useEffect hook.

```
  const marks = [
    { id: 1, marks: 1 },
    { id: 2, marks: 20 },
    { id: 3, marks: 30 },
    { id: 4, marks: 40 }
  ]

  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  const transformSpecificMark = (marks, id) => {
    setData(
      marks.map(item =>
        item.id === id
          ? { ...item, marks: marks + 1 }
          : item
      ))
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    transformSpecificMark(marks, id)
  }, [id]);
```

---

You can easily transformSpecificMark function to transform all marks etc.

---

Function based on trigger UI event:

```
     const transformSpecificMark = (id) => {
            setData(
              data.map(item =>
                item.id === id
                  ? { ...item, marks: marks + 1 }
                  : item
              ))
          }


<button onClick={() => transformSpecificMark(id)}>Click</button
```

Comment: I don't think `useEffect` is needed here, we might want to increment the marks multiple times which will fail with `useEffect`, a simple function will do it. Also, it's recommended to use the callback function when the next state depends on the previous one

Comment: good conclusion - then add a button - which trigger the function

Comment: In this case You mentioned - the marks variable will change on data, question edited based on your idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do a one liner

```
const updateDataById = (id) => {
      setData(prev =>
          prev.map(e => e.id === id ? {...e, mark: e.mark + 1 } : e )
      )
}
```

Comment: You forgot to spread the rest of the properties

Comment: The properties of the object `e`, not the array

Comment: @Asaf Aviv What would happen if e is not spread in above answer? Would that be a case of mutability?

Comment: Right now you are returning an object with `id` and `mark` properties when the `id` matches, the object might have other properties which will be lost. You can copy all of the object properties just like `Piotr` did in his answer. `{...item}`

Comment: No, this is still an immutable update, you will just lose the other properties of the object. You can read about the [spread syntax here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: @Asaf Aviv true. I didn't spread in this case based on the properties in his predefined object. But better to spread it as a good practice if only a specific property needs to be changed. Updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, but maybe in the future we will add properties, and we might forget to update the function, so it's better to spread it. Also, there is no need to spread `prev` because `.map` already returns a new array